# Securing my drupal website

Tags: security

I'm working on my very first drupal website and it will consist of a login form which will then give the user access to a form. This next form will allow the user to query my database to show the closest matches in the category they search - and when they select one they will able to fill in some details on another form, attach some files and then send the information via email.

Security is the most important factor here as the information is all confidential. Can you help me work out what plugins/modules I should be looking at to make my system most secure. And what possible security problems I need to be aware of?

[Note: I have used cmsmatrix.org to compare what the CMS can do and one thing I've noticed is for Drupal it says it can't do things like ssl logins or ssl pages. So should I even be using Drupal in that case?]

Comment: kindly tag the version of your drupal installation as modules recommended to you (if any) in this context might greatly depend on it

Answer (score 6):

I serve several Drupal sites on HTTPS, I don't see what Drupal has to do with that, that's the webservers job to handle. You can test the login for yourself in via HTTPS on drupal.org.

For querying the database in a safe fashion, I would recommend [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).
For gathering data with forms, the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module. I haven't collected files with Webform, and I'm not sure if that's doable in it's current form. This may require some custom work.

There's a [Securing Drupal guide](http://drupal.org/security/secure-configuration) which also specifically mentions getting HTTPS up.

Answer (score 4):

There are several guides available (free or not-free) which might be useful to you:

- [Secure configuration](http://drupal.org/security/secure-configuration) for Drupal sites
- [Writing secure code](http://drupal.org/writing-secure-code) which is also valuable to understand so you can audit the modules you install.
- [Drupal security team](http://drupal.org/security-team) which contains information about the project's policies like [what to do if your site is defaced](http://drupal.org/node/213320)
- [Drupal Security Report](http://drupalsecurityreport.org/) which is the first report to try to tackle the question of whether Drupal's software and security team are mature enough to be deployed in your organization.
- [Cracking Drupal](http://crackingdrupal.com/) the only book about security in Drupal, which is now available (disclosure: I'm the author ;))